# Ruby on Rails - Login with Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

I'm looking for a good tutorial for Sessions in RoR

Can you recommend me some sites? ( Please not ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to user login/logout functionality - if you're willing to pay for it (I can't recommend enough that you do) Railscast has an excellent episode on authentication: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised.

There are also free episodes on setting up Devise (a gem that does most of the authentication work for you): http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise - but I would again recommend building your own from scratch first so you understand the logic.

If and when you do decide to jump into Devise, their github pages are very helpful as well so check those out: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails

I found the above link very helpful.